# passing an Int from one ViewController to another using a segue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I am trying to pass an int from one VC to another. I am doing it like this.

In my VC1 I am doing a segue`showDetail` when I call the prepareForSegue method. It looks like this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
    News *news = [arrNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"news id is %@",news.new_id);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setNewsId:(int)news.new_id];
    }
}
```

In the Log I get the correct number back. Now in my VC2 I have declared an int like this.

```
@property (nonatomic) int newsId;
```

And my setMethod looks like this.

```
-(void)setNewsId:(int)newsId{
    NSLog(@"news id is %d",newsId);
    self.newsId = newsId;

}
```

When I executed I come in a loop with all big numbers. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: What is the type of news.new_id? Why do you need to cast it to int in your -setNewsId: call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code couse to loop:

```
-(void)setNewsId:(int)newsId{
    NSLog(@"news id is %d",newsId);
    self.newsId = newsId;
}
```

And should be:

```
-(void)setNewsId:(int)newsId{
    NSLog(@"news id is %d",newsId);
    _newsId = newsId;
}
```

Where _newsId is ivar.

**UPD**
Seems that news.new_id has NSNumber type. So extract integer value

```
[segue.destinationViewController setNewsId:[news.new_id integerValue]];
```

Comment: When I do this and I look at the log, I get this news id is 503841632

Comment: Just before I pass it, I put a log. Like you can see above in my PrepareForSegue.   *NSLog(@"news id is %@",news.new_id); * This log is always correct.

Comment: Sorry @StefGeelen, I don't understand your problem. Is value in _newsId wrong or ...?

Comment: Yes the value in _newsId (in VC2) is wrong. In VC1 there is no problem

Comment: You can't just cast an NSNumber as an int to convert it. Use integerValue instead. The big number you are seeing is the pointer address.

Comment: Just do what @AaronBrager said. In line [segue.destinationViewController setNewsId:[news.new_id integerValue]];

Comment: @StefGeelen I've updated answer. Please, confirm that is work for you.

Answer (score 2):

`self.newsId = newsId;` This will call your setter method `setNewsId:`. It causes an infinite loop. Always access the instance variable directly inside the setter and getter.

```
_newsId = newsId;
```

Your actual problem is '(int)news.new_id' this casting. This giving you wrong value try to put a log for this value. I hop  `news.new_id` is a `NSNumber` then either make the property as `NSNumber` type or if you want `int` only take [news.new_id intValue] and set. Do not type cast.